# How do revised versions of USB ports transfer data faster under the same number of pins e.g. USB 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: usb

How do upgraded revisions of the same port (e.g. USB 1.0 is the exact same port as USB 3.0) transfer more data, without the addition of more pins? Or how is Thunderbolt / other protocols over USB C faster than normal USB C?

Comment: FireWire is incompatible with USB, I don’t understand the question, Type-C is a connector the speed of Type-C would be entirely limited by the speed of the USB port revision and it literally could not exceed that limit

Comment: Sorry, i meant Thunderbolt, but the name isn't important. My question exactly is: how can you have faster protocols on the same port?

Comment: USB3 is not the exact same port, it has extra pins in the socket. It just *looks* the same at a quick glance.

Comment: @stickynotememo - It actually does matter. Thunderbolt and FireWire are two entirely different standards. One can be compatible (depending on the version of Thunderbolt we are talking about) with Type-C depending on its revision the other is a decade old standard that has been abandoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do upgraded revisions of the same port (e.g. USB 1.0 is the exact same port as USB 3.0) transfer more data, without the addition of more pins?

Assuming you mean USB **2.0**, it uses different electrical signalling (see [USB PHY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)#Signaling_(USB_PHY))) – I'm not an engineer, but my own guess is that the *much* lower "high/low" voltages (400mV instead of whole 3.6V as mentioned in the article) lead to it being possible to physically switch between "high" and "low" at a higher rate, as voltage change is not completely instant.

(You'll probably want to ask https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead, though.)

The USB 2.0 specification is [freely available](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification); it actually includes both the "USB 2.0" (480 Mbps) mode and the "USB 1.1" (12 Mbps) mode in the same specification.

USB **3.0** does in fact have more pins in the usual type-A/B ports. For type-A you'll find 5 extra pins deep inside the plug and at the very front of the receptacle. (That's not a major change though, both transmit and receive still use 1 pair each, only now they're separate in each direction.)

Ethernet also went from 10 Mbps to 100 Mbps over the same number of wires (1 pair in each direction), which did require higher quality cables (tighter twists for less crosstalk); it also switched from Manchester coding to MLT-3 coding for the signals.

Answer (score 0):

There is a negotiation that takes place (typically in hardware by the use of resistors).

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225424/usb-1-0-host-speed-negotiation-to-usb-2-0-device  has a fairly technical rundown.

I believe that USB3 does something similar - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123662/how-does-usb-3-0-negotiate-power-states